# Powershell Equivalent of this old bat netsh way of obtaining DNS Server and ip from dhcp?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, dns, powershell

Is there a way to do this in Powershell?

```
REM Stop the DNS Service...
REM (not shown here)

REM DHCP DNS Settings
netsh interface ip set dns "<adapter-name>" dhcp

REM DHCP IP
netsh interface ip set address "<adapter-name>" dhcp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really common thing, that PowerShell level 100 stuff. Just search for it, using...

> ['powershell set client dhcp'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20set%20client%20dhcp&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20set%20clientdhcp&sc=0-25&sk=&cvid=A3DC5FB1E2D34D5EAE9F79316EC500A1)
>
> ['powershell netsh dns'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20netsh%20dns&form=ANNTH1&refig=6d657721d61f4653b66730df5ffe251a&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20netsh%20dn&sc=6-19&qs=n&sk=&cvid=6d657721d61f4653b66730df5ffe251a)

And get results with examples ...

> [basic networking powershell cmdlets cheatsheet to replace netsh,
>   ipconfig, nslookup and more](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/02/basic-networking-powershell-cmdlets-cheatsheet-to-replace-netsh-ipconfig-nslookup-and-more)
>
> [replace netsh with windows powershell – basic network cmdlets](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/replace-netsh-with-windows-powershell-basic-network-cmdlets)
>
> [Replacing Netsh with These PowerShell Cmdlets](https://www.nextofwindows.com/replacing-netsh-with-these-powershell-cmdlets)
>
> Change the network adapter to use DHCP The following commands can be
>   used to re-configure a specific network adapter to  use a DHCP
>   assigned address:

```
$netadapter = Get-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet
$netadapter | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Enabled
```

> [Change DNS Servers for Computers with Static IP Addresses](https://thinkpowershell.com/change-dns-servers-for-computers-with-static-ip-addresses)

```
$Adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DHCPEnabled -ne 'True' -and $_.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $null}

$NewDnsServerSearchOrder = "192.168.1.13","192.168.1.14"

$Adapters | ForEach-Object {$_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($NewDnsServerSearchOrder)} | Out-Null
```

> [How To Configure IP Address With PowerShell?](https://www.technig.com/configure-ip-address-using-powershell)
>
> [PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Set Primary and Secondary DNS Server Addresses](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-set-primary-and-secondary-dns-server-addresses)

```
Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex 12 –ServerAddresses (“10.0.0.1”,”10.0.0.2”)
```

Even [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20netsh) videos using the same searce